# Filter Spark Dataframe with a variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Is this even possible in spark dataframe (1.6/2.1)

```
val data="some variable"

df.filter("column1"> data)
```

I can do this with a static value but cant figure out how to do filter by a variable.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `val data` ?

Answer (score 6):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data="some variable"
df.filter(col("column1") > lit(data))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you accomplished that with a literal either since what you have doesn't match any of the `filter` method signatures.

So yes, you can work with a non-literal, but try this:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
df.filter($"column1" > data)
```

Note the `$`, which uses `implicit` conversion to turn the `String` into the `Column` named with that `String`. Meanwhile, this `Column` has a `>` method that takes an `Any` and returns a new `Column`. That `Any` will be your `data` value.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, we can do like this:

```
  int i  =10;

 //for equal condition
  df.select("column1","column2").filter(functions.col("column1").equalTo(i)).show();

 //for greater than or less than
 df.select("no","name").filter(functions.col("no").gt(i)).show();
 df.select("no","name").filter(functions.col("no").lt(i)).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a variable to filter Spark Dataframe.

```
val keyword = "my_key_word"
var keyword = "my_key_word" // if it is a variable

df.filter($"column1".contains(keyword))
df.filter(lower($"column1").contains(keyword)) //if not case sensitive
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do it using [string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)

```
val data="some variable"
df.filter(s"column1 > $data")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val portfolio_name = "Product"

spark.sql("""SELECT
   *
FROM
    Test""").filter($"portfolio_name"===s"$portfolio_name").show(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete demo of filter using `<` `>` `=` on numeric columns where `mysearchid` is a number declared as `val` below...

```
scala>val numRows =10
scala>val ds = spark.range(0, numRows)
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala>val df = ds.toDF("index")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [index: bigint]

scala>df.show
+-----+
|index|
+-----+
|    0|
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
|    6|
|    7|
|    8|
|    9|
+-----+


scala>val mysearchid=9
mysearchid: Int = 9

scala>println("filter with less than ")
filter with less than

scala>df.filter(df("index") < mysearchid).show
+-----+
|index|
+-----+
|    0|
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
|    6|
|    7|
|    8|
+-----+


scala> println("filter with greater than ")
filter with greater than

scala> df.filter(df("index") > mysearchid).show
+-----+
|index|
+-----+
+-----+


scala> println("filter with equals ")
filter with equals

scala> df.filter(df("index") ===  mysearchid).show
+-----+
|index|
+-----+
|    9|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val x = "2020-05-01"
df.filter($"column_name"===x).show()
```

It will work,if you want to compare a variable with the whole column